# Xamarin UITest | adb cmd to open mobile phone Internal storage via mobile screen (not through adb pull command and pull the data )

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

Our application is built on xamarin form and I am performing xamarin UITest to automate the android native app.

**Scenario**: During the validation I have to navigate to Phone's Internal Storage location where I have to open a folder in it(created before this step) -> open sysId.txt file -> validate the content of the file.

**My Approach**: I tried many ways to find a proper command which opens the internal storage via mobile screen but i couldn't find any solution other than using mobile screen coordinates(PFB)

Below commands are used to navigate from home screen to my txt file location (these steps would work only on MotoG8_Plus):

To open Files folder adb shell monkey -p com.google.android.apps.nbu.files -v 10

Swipe Down in Files Folder : adb shell input swipe 500 1000 300 300

Tap on Internal Storage : adb shell input tap 650 1800

Tap on iSpiro Folder : adb shell input tap 1000 1150

Tap on sysId.txt : adb shell input tap 400 400

Tap on HTML viewer : adb shell input tap 300 2000

Note: Above cmd's are working only in Motog8_Plus mobile device as the internal storage path and tap & click coordinates are specific to this device but I'm looking for a generic solution to Open Internal storage folder(via mobile screen) and click on folders by name(e.g click **xyz** folder using adb command by its name xyz)

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: Can someone please look into the issue, I am kind of block to execute the test case, Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As My test should run in other devices i thought to install(material_files.apk) a new file explorer (remove google files) then

1. Open Internal storage:

   ```
   adb shell am start --user 0 -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file://storage/sdcard/" -t resource/folder
   ```
2. Open ABC Folder:

   ```
   adb shell am start --user 0 -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file://storage/sdcard/ABC" -t resource/folder
   ```
3. Open Text File(XYZ.txt):

   ```
   adb shell am start --user 0 -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file://storage/sdcard/ABC/XYZ.txt -t text/plain
   ```